# Aspose Pdf : Getting exception for large files

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I try to save the pdf document but I am getting below Exception.

"Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."

```
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveRange(Int32 index, Int32 count)
at Aspose.Pdf.Paragraphs.RemoveRange(Int32 index, Int32 count)
at Aspose.Pdf.Cell.   (Table , Page , Double , Double , Boolean )
at Aspose.Pdf.Row.Process(Table , Double& , Double& , Boolean , Int32& , Int32& , Double , Double , Page , List`1 )
at Aspose.Pdf.Table.Process(Double& , Double& , Boolean , Double , Double , Page , Boolean , List`1 )
at    .   .Process()
at Aspose.Pdf.FloatingBox.Process(Double& , Double& , Double , Double , MarginInfo , Page , Double , List`1 )
at    .   .Process()
at Aspose.Pdf.Page.   (Page )
at Aspose.Pdf.Page.ProcessParagraphs()
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.ProcessParagraphs()
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save(Stream output)
at Aspose.Pdf.Document.Save(String outputFileName)
```

I have 10 list of tables, for 1-5 list it is working fine. But if I giving 6-10 list it is not working and giving above exception.

I have used just normal save only.

```
doc.save(filepath);
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete code snippet, so that we can test the scenario and try figuring out the reasons behind this exception.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the exception using sample code, and we couldn't share the original code. :-( Are you face this type of error before? and If you have a chance can you explain me how I can avoid this exception.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I could not recall a scenario where we encountered such issue. However it appears that when parsing/manipulating various objects inside PDF document, your application is generating this problem. Nevertheless, until or unless we have tested the scenario, we might not be able to share the exact reasons behind this problem. Also please share which version of API you are using.

Comment: We are using latest 10.9 version of Aspose pdf

Comment: As requested, kindly share the sample project which can help us in replicating the issue in our environment. You may consider posting the query with sample project in Aspose.Pdf product support forum, as its a central location to manage all issues/enhancement requests.